# biblatex citestyle "phys"

Tags: biblatex

I'm new to the biblatex environment and I'm trying desperately to have clean citation in my documents.
I want to have something like:

I want to cite this <sup>1</sup>

**References**

<sup>1</sup>  Author, etc....

I manage to get the right form in the "Reference" section by applying this preamble and more precisely the "phys" style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

But unfortunately when I set a `\cite` in my text I get the following form:

I want to cite this [1]

and not the wanted "footnote" formatting as above

Thanks for help and sorry for my poor formatted question.

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126113/formatting-cites-in-foonotes-and-bibliography-differently-using-biblatex?rq=1

Comment: Mmmh I see. Your trying to say that this is non standard and I should write a full custom bibliographic style myself ?

Comment: The problem with the code proposed in this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126113/formatting-cites-in-foonotes-and-bibliography-differently-using-biblatex?rq=1) is that it adds real footnotes my the references. My wish is only on the citation formatting being like a footnote as shown in the question, not adding footnotes.

Comment: Not a whole bib style, but some customisations. It's easier with biblatex than with .bst files. Using `\supercite` instead of `\cite` should be enough.

Comment: @Bernard I don't really get your point...

Comment: @Thomas Produit: Doesn't \supercite produce a footnote-like number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\supercite{mykeyword}` or `\autocite{mykeyword}` (thanks, Joseph Wright!) instead of `\cite{mykeyword}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@BOOK{Lear71,
  author = {Lear, Edward},
  title = {Nonsense songs, stories, botany, and alphabets},
  year = {1871},
  publisher = {James R. Osgood and Company},
  location = {Boston}}

@BOOK{Lear80,
  author = {Lear, Edward},
  title = {Lear’s Book of Nonsense},
  year = {1880},
  publisher = {Frederick Warne and Co},
  location = {London}}
\end{filecontents}

\title{Literature Review: \\
\textbf{Nonsense Literature}}


\author{The Scroobious Bird}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{\textit{Introduction}}
Some Text \supercite{Lear80}. Some more text \supercite{Lear71}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]